# R: Remove a Raster Attribute Table from raster for writing to Tiff

Tags: raster, r, attribute-table

I've been given a large raster with an in-built RAT with all sorts of RGB data and classes etc etc, but it's been done a bit poorly and I would like to quickly rebuild it myself.

When i read into R and then writeRaster to GeoTiff, it's a right old mess, so i'd like to remove the RAT entirely, how is this done?

```
# here's a raster with RAT
require(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10,nrow=10,xmn=0,xmx=10,ymn=0,ymx=10)
r[] <- sample(1:4,100,rep=T)

# ratify and add some attributes
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$letters <- LETTERS[1:4]
rat$names <- c("Tom","Tim","Jane","Jessica")
rat$vals <- c(0.265,0.456,0.037,0.756)

# set RAT
levels(r) <- rat
```

How do i get rid of the RAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be as easy as that?

```
s <- setValues(raster(r), r[])
s

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1, 4  (min, max)
```